# RobotFramework: xpath's href seen as "not a valid XPath expression."

Tags: xpath, robotframework

Line 1 there does find the selector

```
Wait Until Element Is visible  xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Download selected certificate')]
```

Then when i try to get the href element

```
${url}=    Get Element Attribute   xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Download selected certificate')]/@href
```

It fails
Error says

InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(text(),'Download selected certificate')]/ because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(text(),'Download selected certificate')]/' is not a valid XPath expression.

Im not sure why as i have a working unrelated example with similar syntax

```
${url}=    Get Element Attribute   xpath=//tr[contains(b/span, Jul)][${row_number}]/td[5]/span/a/@href
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xpath, a value of `//a[contains(text(),'Download selected certificate')]/@href` would return an object which is the href attribute of that `a` tag.

In Selenium2Library though, when calling `Get Element Attribute`, `@` designates the attribute name to get the value of, for a particular dom elelement.
So what that keyword does is to split that string on the last `@`, get a webelement on the 1st part, and retrieve the target attribute's (the 2nd part of the split) value.
Doing so, it ends up with a locator for the element being `//a[contains(text(),'Download selected certificate')]/` - and that trailing `/` makes it an invalid xpath.

The solution is simple - lose the trailing slash; e.g.:

```
${url}=    Get Element Attribute   xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Download selected certificate')]@href
```

As for why your last sample works - it beats me too :)